# Zimbra Does not send email to local and External Account

Tags: postfix, zimbra

i am getting this Error

```
Mar 30 06:09:28 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[6381]: 0EC7DFC5EB: to=<******@hotmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hotmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

When i try this in Gmail i get this

```
Mar 30 06:13:16 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[9314]: 7987CFC5EF: to=<*****@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=0.23, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.17, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as ADFA5FC5EE)
```

I do not see it anywhere in the Gmail.

I setup Zimbra in digitalocean Droplet, now i try to send email and I am getting this? i used a free domain name to setup the A and MX respectively and checking on the URL it points and works fine
Now i want to send email and this is what I am getting as error in return

Answer (score 0):

[As I stated in your other post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1058790/zimbra-does-not-send-email-local-and-external/1058852#1058852), you have DNS issues on your Droplet. Review /etc/resolv.conf (assuming Linux) and troubleshoot DNS issues for your Droplet.