# Zimbra Does not send Email (local and External)

Tags: email, postfix, zimbra

So i managed to get the Zimbra installed today, and Its on here

https://mail.betheluniversityeu.gq:7071/zimbraAdmin/
i am using Digital ocean as VPS to run the mailserver

I have this issue, when I check on MXTOOLBOX it appears to be working beautifully well. Now i want to send email to be sure it sends email and I decide to check the email Log like this tail -f /var/log/mail.log , I am getting this as response

```
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtpd[27035]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: <emeka.iwuagwu@betheluniversityeu.gq>: Sender address                                                                                         triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<emeka.iwuagwu@betheluniversityeu.gq> to=<e.iwuagwu@hotmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<betheluniversityeu.gq>
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtpd[27035]: BB9FEFC604: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtpd[27035]: BB9FEFC604: filter: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: <emeka.iwuagwu@betheluniversityeu.gq>: Sender addre                                                                                        ss triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<emeka.iwuagwu@betheluniversityeu.gq> to=<iwuagwuemmy@yahoo.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<betheluniversityeu.gq>
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtpd[27035]: BB9FEFC604: filter: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: <emeka.iwuagwu@betheluniversityeu.gq>: Sender addre                                                                                        ss triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<emeka.iwuagwu@betheluniversityeu.gq> to=<e.iwuagwung@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<betheluniversityeu.gq>
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/cleanup[27038]: BB9FEFC604: message-id=<804426382.31.1617086110640.JavaMail.zimbra@betheluniversityeu.gq>
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/qmgr[27852]: BB9FEFC604: from=<aaaaa@betheluniversityeu.gq>, size=1084, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtpd[27035]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=3 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[27042]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[27042]: D887DFC607: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/cleanup[27038]: D887DFC607: message-id=<804426382.31.1617086110640.JavaMail.zimbra@betheluniversityeu.gq>
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/qmgr[27852]: D887DFC607: from=<aaaaaa@betheluniversityeu.gq>, size=1526, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[27042]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=3 data=1 quit=1 commands=7

//Mail Sends here 

Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27040]: BB9FEFC604: to=<*****@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.19, delays=0.02/0.02/0                                                                                        .01/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 25                                                                                        0 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D887DFC607)

Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27040]: BB9FEFC604: to=<*********@hotmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.19, delays=0.02/0.02/0                                                                                        .01/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 25 0 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D887DFC607)

Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27040]: BB9FEFC604: to=<**********@yahoo.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.19, delays=0.02/0.02/0                                                                                        .01/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 25  0 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D887DFC607)

Mar 30 06:35:10 betheluniversityeu postfix/qmgr[27852]: BB9FEFC604: removed
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/amavisd/smtpd[27045]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/amavisd/smtpd[27045]: 1BE7DFC606: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/cleanup[27038]: 1BE7DFC606: message-id=<804426382.31.1617086110640.JavaMail.zimbra@betheluniversityeu.gq>
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/qmgr[27852]: 1BE7DFC606: from=<aaaaa@betheluniversityeu.gq>, size=1839, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/amavisd/smtpd[27045]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=3 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27040]: D887DFC607: to=<*******@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=0.24, delays=0.05/0.01/0                                                                                        /0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1BE7DFC606)
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27040]: D887DFC607: to=<********@hotmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=0.24, delays=0.05/0.01/0                                                                                        /0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1BE7DFC606)
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27040]: D887DFC607: to=<********@yahoo.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=0.24, delays=0.05/0.01/0                                                                                        /0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1BE7DFC606)
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/qmgr[27852]: D887DFC607: removed


Mail Returns here 
//--------------------------
Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27046]: 1BE7DFC606: to=<*****@hotmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=                                                                                        deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hotmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)

Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/error[27047]: 1BE7DFC606: to=<******@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.3, sta                                                                                        tus=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)

Mar 30 06:35:11 betheluniversityeu postfix/smtp[27048]: 1BE7DFC606: to=<*****@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=                                                                                        deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=yahoo.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

Any idea why it does not Send Emails, Could this be because I have not setup SPF, DKIM?

Answer (score 0):

You have name service errors - Zimbra isn't able to resolve DNS.

Comment: How can he tell that?